# Google+ sync automatically being enabled

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-plus, oneplus-one

I have setup my phone to to backup all my photos to Google drive. Under the Google sync settings there are three items

- Google+
- Google+ Photos
- Google+ Uploads

I keep only Google+ photos checked so that sync can happen. But if I check the settings after sometime, I find Google+ and Google+ Uploads automatically being checked.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to turn off syncing of Google+ but keep photo backup enabled?

Comment: I can't say to be honest, but what caught my eye is: CyanogenMod. I have tried it on about 15 devices over about 3 or 4 years and NEVER have I had an install without bugs and quirks. I can't even guess why this happens, but I'd start with that ROM to be honest. I find usually: Wifi Issues, GPS doesn't work, Stutters, Screen Flickering, **Default Settings not retained**, random reboots and it goes on and on. Maybe a different ROM first?

Comment: @RossC: Actually this is the OnePlus One. Cyanogenmod IS the default OS on this phone. Specifically Cyanogenmod 11s. The phone is great BTW. http://oneplus.net/

Comment: Oh yeah of course! Disregard, totally different scenario. I want one myself, cool little device. Could be a quirk but I'll look around.

Comment: My guess would be that they are all linked as there is an Auto-Backup function in Google+ settings, connected to the Photos app.

Comment: I am seeing similar behaviour with stock Lollipop 5.0.2 on my Moto G. My suggested workaround is to disable auto-update for those apps and see if that helps. But if anyone has a fuller insight of this I would gladly hear it.